# Osmdroid as alternative to Mapbox

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I am currently using MapBox SDK to display raster map tiles within an Java/Kotlin implemented Android app. However, I want to replace the Mapbox SDK with an alternative primarily because, as far as I understand, when I use MapBox SDK in my app even just to display other third party map tiles, it will result in some location information about my user's being intermittently sent to Mapbox. I am now considering osmdroid and was looking for some input on whether this will be an appropriate alternative. I am using Here maps as the primary source of raster map tiles [though I also have limited coverage map tile server (generated from OSM) of my own which I do not currently use but might as an alternative if needed]. Within the app, the functionality that I want to implement is relatively simple:

(1) Display map tiles based on standard X,Y,Z system
(2) Display tap-able icons overlaid at certain (GPS) locations on the displayed maps
(3) Allow user to zoom in-out or scroll across the displayed map

However, one absolute key requirement is that none of my user location information will be shared as part of the terms of usage for the SDK.

Is Osmdroid SDK a possible suitable alternative to mapbox SDK for this ?

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Realize that the maintainers of Osmdroid SDK can change their SDK at any time. However given that it is open-source, you should review the source code itself (along with its support libraries) to see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2017, I've been using the OsmDroid SDK quite frequently. The SDK is primarily used to create my situational awareness map application and to manage my offline GeoPackage raster and vector map collections via OsmDroid GeoPackage API support, though the core GeoPackage API allows me to use online GeoPackage-based map providers.

To respond to your inquiry: No user data, including location, is stored by the OsmDroid APIs. It is merely an SDK for manipulating its MapView (which extends from Android's ViewGroup) and supports loading tile sources from online/offline map databases.

It will be our responsibility to implement our own location positioning codes so that any user position, in addition to other map objects you want to include in the map, can be drawn on the map.

Unlike the Google Maps SDK, no API key is required for the OsmDroid SDK. In fact, it attempts to emulate what the Google Maps SDK can do while remaining royalty-free and open-source license compliant. It primarily serves OpenStreetMap purposes. To improve the OsmDroid experience, a free OsmBonusPack SDK simplifies application use-cases.

https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack

Except that you'll need a TOKEN/API key from the map database provider of your choice for any non-free map databases you want to use as base maps or tile sources. This requires you to code in the necessary parameters for the tile module provider to work.

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Map-Sources

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Really really helpful and answers my question. Before I start into the work to integrate I have one final question. I am not 100% clear whether I MUST seeking granting of WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission or not. I have read in some places that this is ALWAYS needed but it is my intention to only use an ONLINE map tile source (and not to cache any tiles!). The "How to" on GitHub for OSMdroid appears to suggest that in such cases only INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permissions need to be sought. Thanks!

Comment: When permission is required, you can request it on the fly; it is not necessary to request every permission if it has not been checked yet when the app is launched for the first time. You could, for example, write a file import method that copies files from a folder to a working folder that Android will tolerate, such as the application's private folder. This requires the permission WRITE EXTERNAL STORAGE and you can request it one time in the method.

Comment: Always put the OsmDroid default cache folder in the application's private folder so Android doesn't complain and your app works properly.

Comment: Here is my app that makes use of the OsmDroid SDK: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3PNinlktAQ; the issue mentioned has already been resolved by me ;) https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1729

Comment: OsmDroid still requires cache to cache online base maps such as MAPNIK so WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is required unless the cache is stored in the app-specific directory which requires no read/write storage permission.